# Trouble with ruby on rails routes with two word controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, routes, action

I wanted to create a controller called Database Importer.

Here's what I ran:

```
rails generate controller database_importer index
```

Which generated:

```
class DatabaseImporterController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def import
    # to do.
    # Receive the uploaded CSV file and import to the database.
    CSV.foreach("parse.csv") do |row|

    end
  end
end
```

When I visit `http://0.0.0.0:3000/database_importer/index` I get:

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"import", :controller=>"database_importer"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Here is my relevant route:

```
get 'database_importer/index'
```

Why is the routing engine trying to push me towards the import action method?

When I try to change the route to reflect the actual controller name (it doesn't have the underscore), I get:

```
get 'databaseimporter/index'

Routing Error

uninitialized constant DatabaseimporterController
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you also have a route defined like:

```
post 'database_importer/import'
```

I think the form action is what is failing when Rails is trying to generate the route for the form.

Comment: No, I don't have that route added in at all. Why would that need to exist though?

Comment: That fixed the issue... So to be clear: I need to have routes for ALL actions in my controllers for it to work? All actions being all public methods?

Comment: You need to have routes defined for actions that you're using. If you generate HTML by hand and make up some fictitious route than at rendering time Rails wont know - of course the click or form post would fail since the route doesnt exist. But if you use Rails route helpers to generate form actions for you then, yes, the route must exist so Rails can generate the appropriate href/url, etc.